# Cannot use Model Form instance parameter with __init__ function

Tags: django

I am trying to create an edit form for a preexisting entry in one of my models. I need to limit the results for the select users field in my model form. However, when I try to use the instance=MyModelObject parameter for the form to load the prefilled from I get the error as follows.

```
TypeError at /courses/course/asdd
CourseForm.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
```

here is my view.py function

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def addCourse(request, course_id = None):
    #initialize data
    user = request.user
    school = user.school

    #check if submition is POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #if so check if user is linked to a school
        if user.school:
            #check if user has admin access to add courses
            if user.is_admin and user in school.admins:
                #get all form information
                # check if form data is valid
                if form.is_valid():
                    # save the form data to model
                    form.save()       
    
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("courses", 'school'))
            
    #if GET check if user has a related school
    elif user.school:
        #check if user has admin access
        if user.is_admin:
            #check for course code, if so auto fill course info
            if course_id != None:
                #generate filled form
                    course = Course.objects.get(code=course_id)
                    form = CourseForm(instance=course, school=school)
                    return render(request, "app/courses/addCourse.html", {'form': form})
            #if no course code, generate blank form
            else:
                #generate form with school object to limit teacher options to school related users
                form = CourseForm(school)
                return render(request, "app/courses/addCourse.html", {'form': form})
                
    #if all checks fail. Redirect.
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
```

the form code

```
class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):  

    class Meta():
        model = Course
        fields = ('teacher','name','subject','level', 'description', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'start_date', 'end_date')

        widgets = {
            'start_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
            'end_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
            'start_time': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
            'end_time': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        }
    def __init__(self, school, course=None):
        super(CourseForm, self).__init__()
        self.fields['teacher'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, queryset=User.objects.filter(school=school, is_teacher=True))
```

If i remove the def__init__ the instance parameter works but then my 'teacher' input queryset cannot be limited to the users related to 'school'.

Comment: Your overridden `__init__` only accepts `school` and `course` as parameters. It does not accept `instance`.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the remaining parameters to the super init call, otherwise these will remain unhandled:

```
class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = (
            'teacher',
            'name',
            'subject',
            'level',
            'description',
            'start_time',
            'end_time',
            'start_date',
            'end_date',
        )

        widgets = {
            'start_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
            'end_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
            'start_time': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
            'end_time': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, school, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['teacher'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            widget=forms.Select,
            queryset=User.objects.filter(school=school, is_teacher=True),
        )
```

Your `course` parameter however just seems to act as the `instance` parameter, so it makes no sense to have these both.

For the POST codepath, you furthermore don't seem to initialize a form in the first place?

---

> **Note**: Since [**PEP-3135** <sup>[pep]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/), you don't need to call `super(…)` with parameters if the first parameter is the class in which you define the method, and the second is the first parameter (usually `self`) of the function.